# Continued fraction for $[1,2,3,4,5,6,\dots]$

Tags: irrational-numbers, continued-fractions

Any continued fraction that does not terminate or repeat can't be rational or a quadratic irrational.  It is not hard to write something that does not fit these two categories.

Can we still get a closed form for something like:
$$ [1,2,3,4,5, \dots ] = 1 + \cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{3+\cfrac{1}{\dots}}}$$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFractionConstant.html

Comment: Such a constant can be written as the ratio of two modified Bessel functions of the first kind evaluated at $2$.